# how can i send callback to my parent view when call Actions.pop in react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native

I am using https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux for navigation in react native.How can I send callback to my parent view when I call pop actions on it.

```
onPressed() {
    Actions.pop();
}
```

This is how I call pop action on it but I need to send updated value to previous view.

Comment: will i succeed in updated props but when i try to move to next view again then its gives me error
this code is written in me setting screen
Actions.pop();
Actions.refresh({key: 'pageOne', name:'wwwww'});

Only this will work and update the view but when i try to again go to the setting screen then it gives me error

navigation state.children[2].key “scene_settingScreen_1_settingScreen” conflicts with another child!

Answer (score 2):

will I finally solve it by calling empty refresh with props after delay

```
Actions.popTo('pageOne');
    setTimeout(() => {
        Actions.refresh({name:'zzzzar'});
        console.log("zzzz");
    }, 10);
```